# C# struct creation and population

Tags: c#, .net, struct

I'm taking a look at the ZFS file system, and I've come across a reasonably complex  structure, which looks like this:

The whole thing is 128 bytes long, and contains a number of different elements.  Now normally I'd just use bit shifting to obtain what I need, but as I'm fairly new to C# .net, I was wondering if there was an easier way to parse this data.

I've seen the `StructLayout` and `FieldOffset` in C#, but I don't know if it can be used to extract things like three byte integer values, or if it can extract say a nybble from a byte.

Is this something that can be done using a struct, or will I need to implement my own methods for handling the data?

Thanks

[image: https://people.freebsd.org/~gibbs/zfs_doxygenation/html/d0/d3c/structblkptr.html]

Comment: You can't declare types in C# less than a byte in size. For the bitfield-types you can use enums, for nybbles you must extract them using bitwise manipulation operators such as shifts, and and or.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is essentially what I ended up doing.  Thanks for confirming though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in C# you cannot declare a struct like bit fields in C. You may want to represent the structure internally as a `byte[]` and then use `System.BitConverter` to assist you with some conversions. You can extract the 3-byte integers with `BitConverter.ToUInt32` and then mask out a byte. For fields less than 8 bits, you will have to use shifts and bit masking.